# how to retrieve data from db and display it in the laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i want to display the data in a table with edit and delete button for each record in laravel.

i have to display that in the existing page.

admin controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
       return view('admin/admin');
    }

    public function addCategory()
    {
        $category=new Category;
        $category->category_name = Input::get('category');
        $category->save();
        return view('admin/admin');
    }
}
```

my category model

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = "category";
    protected $fillable = [
        'category_name',
    ];
}
```

admin.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .bod{
            background-color:#f8f8f8 ;
            border-shadow: 5px 10px 20px white inset;
            border-width:5px;
            margin-top:-12px;
        }
        .h1{
            font-family:"Book Antiqua";
            font-size: 90px;
            color: red;
            text-align: center;
        }
        div {
            border-radius: 5px;
            /*background-color: #f2f2f2;*/
            /*background-color: #7CA8C1  ;*/
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
            border:2px solid white;
            height: 200px;
            width: 50%;
            margin-left: 50px;
        }
        .txt{
            width: 150px;
            height:25px;
            border: 2px solid white;
        }
        .btn{
            width: 100px;
            height:28px;
            font-weight: bold;
            border: 2px solid white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="bod">
<h1 class="h1">Admin</h1>
<div align="left">

    <form action="{{ route('addCategory') }}" method="get">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <label for="category" style="font-family: 'Book Antiqua';font-size: 48px;color: #9999FF;">Category</label> <br/>
        <table class="table ">
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><input class="txt" type="text" name="category" id="category" placeholder="Enter the Category" ></td>
                <td align="center"></td>
                <td align="center"> <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="ADD" class="btn"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to display all categories added by the admin in the admin page with update and delete button how can i achieve that?

Comment: Your posted code works. That is, the record gets inserted in the table. So either you are running different code from what you've posted here, or you aren't running it properly. Either way only you can tell what it is you've done (or haven't done).

Answer (score 1):

`Address_type` and `Student_type` are your create type.

You forget to create a table `Student_tbl` to carry your insert data.

You can refer this Demo

```
create type Address_type as object ( 
    hno char(4), 
    street varchar2(10), 
    city varchar2(10) 
);

create type Student_type as object ( 
    sno char(4), 
    sname varchar2(10), 
    adddress Address_type 
);

CREATE TABLE Student_tbl(
    V1 Student_type
);

insert into Student_tbl values (Student_type('4567',
                                             'Shan',
                                              Address_type('30','aaa','bbb')
                                             )
                               );
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/501a9)

**EDIT**

If you want to get your customer type like `Address_type` you might do like this.

```
select t.SNO,
       t.SNAME,
       t.adddress.hno,
       t.adddress.street,
       t.adddress.city
from Student_tbl t
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/566503/8)

Comment: here is that coding    create table student_tbl of Student_type;

Comment: it is woking fine thanks but can't we use select * to get the output?why is  thay?

Comment: You can see https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/create_type.htm#LNPLS01375.

In simple terms you can use custom type fields as objects＿